# Obtain properties of a selected image

Tags: vb.net, winforms, openfiledialog

I'm writing in vb.net and I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Okay, so I'm going to show my code, then explain what I need help with.

```
Imports System.IO.File
Imports System.IO.Directory
Imports System.IO

Public Class ImageSelection

    Private Sub ImageSelectionbtn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ImageSelectionbtn.Click

        With OpenFileDialog1
            .Filter = _
"Image File (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Image File (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|Image File (*.bmp)|*.bmp|Image File (*.gif)|*.gif"
            .InitialDirectory = System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures
            .Title = "Select a picture to open"

            If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

                ''''Here is where i need help''''
                Dim MyImage = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
                Dim MyImageWidth
                Dim MyImageHeight
                '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

                With MyPicture 'MyPicture form

                    .Width = MyImageWidth
                    .Height = MyImageHeight
                    .PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
                    MyPicture.Show()
                End With
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

Okay, so what I'm doing is when a user clicks the button, it brings up an open file dialog box that is filtered to only allow .`jpg` .`jpeg` .`bmp` and .`gif`

Now, When they select their picture, I need a way to be able to extract a small bit of information from that selected image.

I need the images height, and the images width, so that I can set another form (with a form docked image box) to the size of that image.

I also need help on setting that `picturebox` in the second form as the image that they selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 With OpenFileDialog1
     .Filter = _
     "Image File (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Image File (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|Image File (*.bmp)|*.bmp|Image File (*.gif)|*.gif"
     .InitialDirectory = System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures
     .Title = "Select a picture to open"

     If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
         ''''Here is where i need help''''
         Dim MyImage = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
         Dim image As Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(MyImage) 'Convert to Image from the selected file

         Dim MyImageWidth As Integer = image.Width 'Get The Width
         Dim MyImageHeight As Integer = image.Height 'Get The Height

         '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
         With MyPicture 'MyPicture form

             .Width = MyImageWidth
             .Height = MyImageHeight
             .PictureBox1.Image = image
             MyPicture.Show()
         End With
     End If
 End With
```

Comment: Will do! I also made some other additions to make it a little easier to read and to get the correct folder path. Instead of using `.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures `   I'm now using `.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures)` :D